# Problems with Sticky effect on Navbar

Tags: html, css

I am facing problems with sticky navbar on my website.

I used the code of [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_navbar_sticky) for this navbar. The problem is that sticky effect on nav menu does not work at all. Menu just disappers during scrolling.

[Link to my website](https://shahar.uz/?region_id=4&_collect_user_info%20%EF%BB%BF=1&page=1&currency_id=1&optype=2&grid_type=square)

Here is how nav menu looks like:
[image]

```
CSS:

      .sticky {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .sticky + .content {
      padding-top: 60px;
    }




    <script>
    window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};
    
    var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");
    var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;
    
    function myFunction() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
        navbar.classList.add("sticky")
      } else {
        navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the sticky code on the container to apply, not directly on the navbar. As sticky works only for siblings and not the whole page.

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
">
<br>

    <div id="navbar-complex" class="scrollmenu tab-content nav nav-tabs">
```

This way it works. after you have some z-index problem but this is different

```css
#id1, #id2{
  width: 50%;
  float:left;
}

#id1{
  background: lightgreen;
}
#id2{
  background: lightblue;
}

#id1 nav{
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:1;
}

#id2 .navContainer{
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  z-index:1;
}

nav{
  background: lightgray;
}
.content{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">
  <h1>What you are doing</h1>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <nav>I am supposed to be sticky</nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>    Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>    Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="id2">
  <h1> What you want</h1>
  <div class="navContainer">
    <nav>I am sticky</nav>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>    Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>    Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
        Lorem ipsum
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```